# How did Kat get shot in Tenet?

Tags: tenet

When uninverted Kat got shot by inverted Sator in *Tenet*, in forward perspective the hole on the wall was fixed but Kat wasn't. What is the difference between Kat and the wall? Shouldn't they both get fixed after being shot? And if assuming this is how this universe works, in the airport sence the inverted protagonist got stabbed by an uninverted protagonist. Why did the inverted protagonist heal after being stabbed but Kat didn't?

Comment: Technically Kat heals if you look at it from the inverted perspective. A wounded Kat sits on the chair. Inverted-Sator fires an inverted bullet at her. It goes through her wound healing it. Inverted Sator takes a healed Kat outside.

Answer (score 1):

Kat was not inverted when shot. Sator and the bullet were, though.

When Sator was shooting Kat, for her that was almost the end of being held hostage by him, but for him it was the beginning of it.

Comment: also for the beginning opera scene, the wall was fixed but the man was dead

Comment: if you argue the wall was inverted, but the wall in opera wasn't

Comment: @hey the wall was not inverted, the bullet was. That's a separate question though, why talk about it for this one?